# Create Return() observable from FirstAsync()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive

In my current project my Test's Assert hapens before the first OnNext happened. How can I wait for the first result before asserting?

Google suggested to use the TestScheduler. Related documentation ([like this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915707/unit-testing-for-an-event-using-reactive-extensions)) seems to suggest I know or care about the timing values, which I don't.

I also tried with await pipeline.SqlStatements.FirstAsync(), but that blocked the entire test and nothing ever returns.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Process_Fileinfos_BatchesHaveSql()
{
    var output = new List<string>();
    var templates = new[] {new FileInfo(@"DropDatabase.txt")};

    var pipeline = new TemplatesPipeline();
    pipeline.SqlStatements.Subscribe(value => output.Add(value));
    pipeline.Process(templates);

    var expected = "dropdatabasescriptcontent";

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, output.First());
}
```

Not sure how to progress here.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's difficult to provide a solution when we can't run the original code that shows the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to block until you get an OnNext from `SqlStatements`, just use:

`Assert.AreEqual(expected, pipeline.SqlStatements.FirstAsync().Wait());`

If you may not get anything, or want a timeout, you'll need to use a different approach.